# php How can i print values with same key

Tags: php

I have some questions

```
this is my orginal array and cood below **will not work** on this array
<?php 
$rijeci=array ( "tekst"=> "osoba" ,"vrsta" => "imenica", 
                "tekst"=> "kuha" , "vrsta" => "glagol", 
                "tekst"=> "crnu" , "vrsta" => "pridjev",  
                "tekst"=> "kavu" , "vrsta" => "imenica",
                "tekst"=> "kopa" , "vrsta" => "glagol")
?>
```

this is my changed array

```
<?php 
$rijeci=array ( "tekst1"=> "osoba" ,"vrsta1" => "imenica", 
                "tekst2"=> "kuha" , "vrsta2" => "glagol", 
                "tekst3"=> "crnu" , "vrsta3" => "pridjev",  
                "tekst4"=> "kavu" , "vrsta4" => "imenica",
                "tekst5"=> "kopa" , "vrsta5" => "glagol")
?>
```

1)How can i echo this 
  *osoba, kuha, crnu, kavu, kopa,*

This will work in  my changed array

```
foreach($rijeci as $key => $var){
    if($var != "imenica" && $var != "glagol"  && $var != "pridjev" )
        echo "$var "  ;
```

2) how can i echo this 
*Imenice: osoba kavu
Glagol: kuha kopa
Pridjev: crnu*

This will work in  my changed array but Is there any other way to print this?

```
    $prethodna = null;
    if($m=="prikazVrstaRijeci"){
    echo "Imenice:\n" ;
foreach ($rijeci as $kljuc => $vrijednost){
    if($vrijednost == "imenica"){
        if($prethodna) {
          echo "$prethodna ";
       }
    }
    $prethodna = $vrijednost;
}
echo "<br />";
echo "Glagol:\n" ;
foreach ($rijeci as $kljuc => $vrijednost){
    if($vrijednost == "glagol"){
        if($prethodna) {
            echo "$prethodna ";
        }
    }
    $prethodna = $vrijednost;
}
echo "<br />";
echo "Pridjev:\n" ;
foreach ($rijeci as $kljuc => $vrijednost){
    if($vrijednost == "pridjev"){
        if($prethodna) {
            echo "$prethodna ";
        }
    }
    $prethodna = $vrijednost;
}
}
```

How can i print 1.) 2.) question in my orginal array? is this possible?

Comment: you can't have same key again in an array

Comment: Your original array will only have 2 values.  Each time you re-define a key, it'll replace the old value.

Comment: thx  I assumed, when I try to print whole array it will output  only the last two values. just want to check with you :)

Comment: why not `$rijeci = array('tekst' => array(........), 'vrsta' => array(.....))`?

Answer (score 0):

you cant have same key with different value you can change array to this

```
$rijeci=array ("osoba" ,"imenica", 
               "kuha" ,  "glagol", 
              "crnu" , "pridjev",  
             "kavu" , "imenica",
             "kopa" , "glagol")
```

now This code Work

```
foreach($rijeci as $key => $var){
if($var != "imenica" && $var != "glagol"  && $var != "pridjev" )
    echo $var;
```

in this array for Echo That List You can do Like This

```
 <?php 
 $rijeci=array ( "tekst1"=> "osoba" ,"vrsta1" => "imenica", 
            "tekst2"=> "kuha" , "vrsta2" => "glagol", 
            "tekst3"=> "crnu" , "vrsta3" => "pridjev",  
            "tekst4"=> "kavu" , "vrsta4" => "imenica",
            "tekst5"=> "kopa" , "vrsta5" => "glagol")
 foreach($rijeci as $key => $var){
   switch( $var){
     case "osoba":
       echo $var; 
     break;
     case "kuha":
       echo $var; 
     break;
     case "crnu":
       echo $var; 
     break;
     case "kavu":
       echo $var; 
     break;
     case "kopa":
       echo $var; 
     break;
   }
   echo ",";

 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get your first example working how you want it to.  A PHP array can only contain a single value for a given key.  A `var_dump()` on your array will show you that you can't print the values you want *because they aren't there*.  What you can do, however, is use nested arrays like so:

```
$rijeci=array ( array("tekst"=> "osoba" ,"vrsta" => "imenica"),
                array("tekst"=> "kuha" , "vrsta" => "glagol"),
                array("tekst"=> "crnu" , "vrsta" => "pridjev"),
                array("tekst"=> "kavu" , "vrsta" => "imenica"),
                array("tekst"=> "kopa" , "vrsta" => "glagol"));

foreach ($rijeci as $pair) {
    print $pair['tekst'];
    print " ";
    print $pair['vrsta'];
    print "\n";
}
```

You can also use named indexes in your nested arrays, giving you something like:

```
$rijeci = array(
    'imenica' => array('osoba', 'kavu'),
    'glagol' => array('kuha', 'crnu'),
    'pridjev' => array('crnu'),
    );

foreach ($rijeci as $vrsta => $stuff) {
    print "$vrsta : ";
    foreach ($stuff as $tekst) {
        print "$tekst, ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Alternately, you can write that loop like:

```
foreach ($rijeci as $vrsta => $stuff) {
    print "$vrsta : ";
    print implode($stuff, ',');
    print "\n";
}
```

Hopefully this is enough to get you on the road to a solution.